# Would a live session use swap when Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is Hibernated?

Tags: boot, grub2, live-usb, hibernate

Whenever I boot into an **Ubuntu/Fedora** live session, i see that they use my swap space.
So, I wanted to know: If I **hibernate my current** Ubuntu Session, and boot to an Ubuntu/Fedora **Live Session**, would these still use the swap partition, **thereby deleting**  its previous contents?
If they do, would using **noswap** in the grub parameters, make them not use swap.
My Setup: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, which I intent to hibernate and boot to a live session entry in my Grub menu, which was added using **grml** **[link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot#grml-rescueboot)**.
So, if I add **noswap** for these two in my grub.cfg file, would it prevent these two iso`s from deleting the previous hobernation data?